# How can I list or discover queues on a RabbitMQ exchange using python?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

I need to have a python client that can discover queues on a restarted RabbitMQ server exchange, and then start up a clients to resume consuming messages from each queue. How can I discover queues from some RabbitMQ compatible python api/library?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't any way of doing this. That's nothing to do with Python, but because AMQP doesn't define any method of queue discovery.

In any case, in AMQP it's clients (consumers) that declare queues: publishers publish messages to an exchange with a routing key, and consumers determine which queues those routing keys go to. So it does not make sense to talk about queues in the absence of consumers.

Answer (score 51):

There does not seem to be a direct AMQP-way to manage the server but there is a way you can do it from Python.  I would recommend using a *subprocess* module combined with the `rabbitmqctl` command to check the status of the queues.

I am assuming that you are running this on Linux.  From a command line, running:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

will result in:

```
Listing queues ...
pings   0
receptions      0
shoveled        0
test1   55199
...done.
```

(well, it did in my case due to my specific queues)

In your code, use this code to get output of `rabbitmqctl`:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
print stdout_value
```

Then, just come up with your own code to parse `stdout_value` for your own use.

Comment: For me, this runs a wrapper script which refuses to continue if I'm not root.

I can run the underlying binary (/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl) directly, though, if I make sure that my ~/.erlang.cookie file matches RabbitMQ's.

Comment: Running `rabbitmqctl list_queues` results in `Error: could not recognise command`

Answer (score 31):

You can add plugin rabbitmq_management

```
sudo /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Then use rest-api

```
import requests

def rest_queue_list(user='guest', password='guest', host='localhost', port=15672, virtual_host=None):
    url = 'http://%s:%s/api/queues/%s' % (host, port, virtual_host or '')
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
    queues = [q['name'] for q in response.json()]
    return queues
```

I'm using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library in this example, but it is not significantly.

Also I found library that do it for us - [pyrabbit](http://pyrabbit.readthedocs.org/)

```
from pyrabbit.api import Client
cl = Client('localhost:15672', 'guest', 'guest')
queues = [q['name'] for q in cl.get_queues()]
```

Comment: How do we get if the consumer is onine/ running  ?

Comment: I suspect this will only show queues that the node has seen. There might be other queues on other nodes.

Answer (score 6):

Since I am a RabbitMQ beginner, take this with a grain of salt, but there's an interesting **[Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/09/07/management-plugin-preview-release/)**, which exposes an HTTP interface to "From here you can manage exchanges, queues, bindings, virtual hosts, users and permissions. Hopefully the UI is fairly self-explanatory."

http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/09/07/management-plugin-preview-release/

Answer (score 3):

I use https://github.com/bkjones/pyrabbit. It's talks directly to RabbitMQ's mgmt plugin's API interface, and is very handy for interrogating RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 2):

Management features are due in a future version of AMQP. So for now you will have to wait till for a new version that will come with that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I found this works for me, /els being my demo vhost name..

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues --vhost /els
```

Answer (score 0):

pyrabbit didn't work so well for me; However, the Management Plugin itself has its own command line script that you can download from your own admin GUI and use later on (for example, I downloaded mine from

```
http://localhost:15672/cli/
```

for local use)

Answer (score 0):

I would use simply this:
Just replace the user(default= guest), passwd(default= guest) and port with your values.

```
import requests
import json

def call_rabbitmq_api(host, port, user, passwd):
  url = 'http://%s:%s/api/queues' % (host, port)
  r = requests.get(url, auth=(user,passwd))
  return r

def get_queue_name(json_list):
  res = []
  for json in json_list:
    res.append(json["name"])
  return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
  host = 'rabbitmq_host'
  port = 55672
  user = 'guest'
  passwd = 'guest'
  res = call_rabbitmq_api(host, port, user, passwd)
  print ("--- dump json ---")
  print (json.dumps(res.json(), indent=4))
  print ("--- get queue name ---")
  q_name = get_queue_name(res.json())
  print (q_name)
```

Referred from here: https://gist.github.com/hiroakis/5088513#file-example_rabbitmq_api-py-L2