# How can I list queues on a RabbitMQ exchange using Java?

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp

I had two host every host have some queue.I want to list all queue declared by other node.
On basis of that queues, I have to perform some operation.

I didn't get any method which will list all queues from amqp server.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I list or discover queues on a RabbitMQ exchange using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287941/how-can-i-list-or-discover-queues-on-a-rabbitmq-exchange-using-python)

Comment: **rabbitmqctl list_queues ** we can pass this command through java and list the queue list.

Comment: @pinepain Python != Java

Comment: @eburnside Thanks for bringing this up. The culprit is not the language here but that the fact that AMQP protocol doesn't have a feature to list bound queues on the exchange, but with RabbitMQ this could be done via REST API regards the language. So the way I see it, the question and solution is language agnostic. Well, at least it was the case 5+ years ago. If things got changed and I missed sth, I would appreciate to be educated about it. Otherwise, the suggest question and answer(s) there are relevant to the problem. Regards the language.

Answer (score 1):

Spring AMQP does not provide a direct abstraction, but RabbitMQ provides a [ReST API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) via its management plugin.

You can use the Spring `RestTemplate` to query the API.