# Go amqp method to list all currently declared queues?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using streadway/amqp to do a tie in from rabbitmq to our alert system. I need a method that can return a list of all the currently declared queues (exchanges would be nice too!) so that I can go through and get all the message counts.

I'm digging through the api documentation here...

```
http://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Queue
```

...but I don't seem to be finding what I'm looking for. We're currently using a bash call to 'rabbitmqctl list_queues' but that's a kludge way to get this information, requires a custom sudo setting, and fires off hundreds of log entries a day to the secure log.

edit: method meaning, 'a way to get this piece of information' as opposed to an actual call, though a call would be great I don't believe it exists.

Comment: this is a feature request for a library, and should be posted on their issue list as such: https://github.com/streadway/amqp/issues

Comment: It actually turns out to be a limitation of the amqp spec. There's no way to do administrative functions like this in band, you have to do something backend specific (in my case calls to the rabbitmq management plugin api)

Comment: This is presented as a valid question -- not a feature request.  A good answer is provided as well.

Answer (score 11):

Answered my own question. There isn't a way! The amqp spec doesn't have a standard way of finding this out which seems like a glaring oversight to me. However, since my backend is rabbitmq with the management plugin, I can make a call to that to get this information.

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286370/5076297 (in python, I'll just have to translate this and probably also figure out the call to get vhosts):

```
import requests

def rest_queue_list(user='guest', password='guest', host='localhost', port=15672, virtual_host=None):
    url = 'http://%s:%s/api/queues/%s' % (host, port, virtual_host or '')
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
    queues = [q['name'] for q in response.json()]
    return queues
```

edit: In golang (this was a headache to figure out as I haven't done anything with structures in years)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {

    type Queue struct {
        Name string `json:name`
        VHost string `json:vhost`
    }

    manager := "http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/"
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", manager, nil)
    req.SetBasicAuth("guest", "guest")
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)

    value := make([]Queue, 0)
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&value)
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

Output looks like this (I have two queues named hello and test)

```
[{hello /} {test /}]
```