# Is there a way to get a list of all declared queues in rabbitmq?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'm using .net Rabbit libraries and i didn't found a way to this with those libraries, only with rabbit Rest API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287941/how-can-i-list-or-discover-queues-on-a-rabbitmq-exchange-using-python) question, there is no direct implementation for getting list of queues in either python or c# at the moment.

Comment: are you sure about this?

Comment: Yes, also I have checked the latest version of c# api.

Comment: I have done the same as some of the suggestions in the linked post (using the HTTP API)